# Select all the people that have the same salary

Tags: sql, select, equals

I have problems finding a solution to an SQL  query. This is probably a very obvious beginner question but I can't seem to get the results that I'm after. I have a table that looks something like the following:

```
|Name |Station|Salary|
|Bob  |1      |2000  |
|Steve|2      |1750  |
|Mark |3      |2050  |
|Lisa |4      |2200  |
|Hans |5      |2000  |
```

I would like to select the names of the people in this table that have the same salary. The result should of course be **Bob** and **Hans**.

Comment: Thank you so much, your help is much appreciated! Have a good one.

Comment: Please upvote all the useful answers and accept the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you join the table against itself on Salary but where the names are separate then this should give you any matching salaried people:

```
SELECT s1.Name, s1.Station, s1.Salary
FROM Staff s1
INNER JOIN Staff s2 ON s1.Salary = s2.Salary AND s1.Name <> s2.Name
```

[Here's a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/349e5d/3) to show it in action

Comment: This is the way to self-join. The answer from @StuartLC is like a Rube Goldberg machine that only works on MySql. :P

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks! but the upvotes to this answer underestimate the out of box solution. New learning, thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT Name
FROM table1 
WHERE Salary IN (
    SELECT Salary
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY Salary
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: the most simplest and easy to understand..!!

Answer (score 4):

If you determine the salary bands which have more than one employee, you can then join back to it as a derived table:

```
SELECT e.Name, e.Station 
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT Salary
   FROM Employee
   GROUP BY Salary
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) grp ON e.Salary = grp.Salary;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd7dd/1)

Answer (score 2):

Most databases support window functions.  The simple method to do this is to count the number of people that have a given salary.  Then choose those people.  Here is an easy method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by salary) as salarycnt
      from table t
     ) t
where salarycnt > 1
order by salary;
```

Answer (score 2):

TRY THIS:

```
SELECT E1.Name, E1.Salary
FROM Employee E1, Employee E2
WHERE E1.Salary = E2.Salary
AND E1.Name <> E2.Name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e34b

Comment: "E1.Name <> E2.Name" condition is incorrect one: the query'll return two records ("Bob, Hans" and "Hans, Bob") instead of one ("Bob, Hans")

Answer (score 1):

Use below Query:

```
with datatab as
(
 select 'Bob' Name,   1 Station, 2000  Salary from dual union
 select 'Steve' Name,   2 Station, 1750  Salary from dual union
 select 'Mark' Name,   3 Station, 2050  Salary from dual union
 select 'Lisa' Name,   4 Station, 2200  Salary from dual union
 select 'Hans' Name,   5 Station, 2000  Salary from dual union
 select 'Test' Name,   6 Station, 1750  Salary from dual
)

SELECT NAME, sTATION, SALARY  FROM DATATAB
WHERE SALARY IN 
(
   SELECT Salary
   FROM datatab
   GROUP BY Salary
   HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
);
```

As someone suggested in Edits, The Query would be:

```
SELECT NAME, sTATION, SALARY  FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE SALARY IN 
(
   SELECT Salary
   FROM TABLE_NAME
   GROUP BY Salary
   HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select a.name, a.salary from
(
Select count(salary) as cnt, salary from staff group by salary having count(salary) > 1

)as X
Inner join staff a on a.Salary=x.salary

order by a.salary:

Answer (score 0):

Use *aliases* when you have to put one and the same table two or more times:

```
select t1.Name,
       t2.Name,
       t1.Salary 
  from MyTable t1,
       MyTable t2
 where t1.Station > t2.Station and -- if Station is id 
       -- t1.Name > t2.Name -- if Name is in fact an id
       t1.Salary = t2.Salary
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select COUNT(*) as NumberOfPerson,salary from tblEmployee group by salary having COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: please try adding details / explanation to code that will make it easy to understand for other also also that lands on this page suffering from from similar error

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

Select  *  from  worker
where salary in (select salary from worker
group by salary
having count(1)>1);

Answer (score 0):

lets say table name is: **employee**

select distinct e.name, e.salary from employee e, employee e1 where
e.salary = e1.salary and e.name != e1.name;

Answer (score 0):

First Solution :

Select e1.name from employee e1
inner join employee e2 on e1.salary=e2.salary AND e1.name <> e2.name

Second easy solution:

Select name from employee
where salary In (Select salary from employee
group by salary
having count(*)>1)

Answer (score 0):

SUPPOSE WE HAVE TABLE NAMELY AS EMP3 WHICH ONTEIN COLUMNS AS FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALRY, DEPARTMENT_ID, COMMISSION, ETC.

NOW WE HAVE TO SELECT RECORDS OF EMPLOYEES WHO HAVE THE SAME SALARY.

LET'S GET OUTPUT WITH THE HELP OF SELF JOIN.

HERE WE ARE JOINING THE SAME TABLE WITH ITSELF TO GET RECORDS WHO HAVE THE SAME SALARY.

```
SELECT E1.FIRST_NAME AS FN,E1.SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES E1 INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E2 ON E1.SALARY=E2.SALARY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Treating same table as a separate two table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.username, T.salary
FROM account T, account T
WHERE T.salary = T.salary
AND T.username <> T.username
ORDER BY salary;
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want the quantity of people with the same salary.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY salary
```